# How to get back file in node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

In node, I am using `multer`. From UI, I am sending file & other data as multipart formdata. In node, I am receiving the text data in `req.body` & file in `req.files` object. How can I get the actual uploaded file`(.xlsx)` from `buffer` of `req.files`?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the actual file using multer in your node express backend.
Even you not tell which tools and libraries you are using in frontend.
You also did not share you code.
Here is cool article for react to node file uploading:
[Here it Goes](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/)
If you are not using react and using simple html and js then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qzmri1WaaE) will be a good video for you. If you watch this video, this is for images but all code is same just you have to change extensions names.
If both the cases are not for you then share you code so the programmers can watch where are you making mistakes.